# Android How to know which Contacts have my application installed?

Tags: android, contacts

I'm creating an application where I need to know who in my Contacts HAS my application installed on their phone. I already have a contact list in a ListView displayed in my application, but those contacts shown need to be restricted to those who have my application installed.  Is there any way to tell?  Thanks!

Comment: my gut tells me this isn't possible through android apis - would you like it if your friends could query if you had <any embarassing app> installed?

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna have to store that information somewhere in the cloud.

You need an activity or service that will store the user information somewhere (eg a dababase) and you'll have to get the info for all your users from there in order to filter your list view's adapter.

Comment: Thanks!  Would this require a username/password account system or could I somehow add every user who downloads the app to the database to know who has it?

Comment: Yes, you don't need an account service for that.